# Java Swing - My JPanel is eating my JButton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, jtextarea

To create my GUI I created a number of subclasses of `JPanel`, each of those solving a specific layout problem.

The first is the `AltBoxLayout_JPanel`, inspired by the answer to a question I posed time ago (link: [Setting the height of a JTextFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61836188/setting-the-height-of-a-jtextframe)): it simply is a couple of `JPanel`s nestled one within the other, the inner one with a `BoxLayout` to distribute the components in the preferred way, the outer one with a `BorderLayout` to squeeze the components to their minimal dimension.

The second is the `Fieldset`, inspired by the HTML tag with the same name: again it is made by two nestled `JPanel`s, the outer one with a `TitleBorder`, the inner one that is given in the constructor and whose purpose is to set up the layout inside the `Fieldset` zone.

I tested those two specialized components separately, with good results, and was satisfied by them. Recently I needed to use them both: I wanted a `JButton` and a `JTextArea` to be displayed one over the other without being artificially expanded (i.e. inside a `AltBoxLayout_JPanel`), and surrounded by a border (i.e. the `AltBoxLayout_JPanel` inside a `Fieldset`). Since all of my components were already tested, I was sure it would go well.

It didn't.

Somehow my `JButton` is not visible anymore. I know it is there (I checked) and I *assume* it is covered by the `JTextArea`, but I have no further information. Below is my code.

Any help in rescuing my `JButton` would be really appreciated!

---

```
public class StackOverflowQuestion extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5644282466098799568L;

    private JPanel contentPanel;
        

    // Display area
        
    private Fieldset fieldset;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextArea jTextArea;
        
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public StackOverflowQuestion() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 300, 140);
        contentPanel = new JPanel();
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPanel);
        
    // Testing new components
        
    //  JPanel fieldsetLayoutPanel = new JPanel();
    //  BoxLayout fieldsetLayout = new BoxLayout(fieldsetLayoutPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
    //  fieldsetLayoutPanel.setLayout(fieldsetLayout);
        
        JPanel fieldsetLayoutPanel_2 = new AltBoxLayout_JPanel(BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
        
        this.fieldset               = new Fieldset("Fieldset title", fieldsetLayoutPanel_2, null);
        this.button                 = new JButton("Button text");
        this.jTextArea              = new JTextArea("JTextArea here!");
        this.jTextArea.setRows(5);
        this.jTextArea.setColumns(20);
        this.button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Action executed: " + arg0.toString());
            }});
            
        fieldset.add(button);
        fieldset.add(jTextArea);
        contentPanel.add(fieldset);

        System.out.println("Analysis of the components of the contentPanel:");
        analyzeLayoutsOfComponentAndSubComponents(contentPanel, 0);
            
        pack();
            
    }

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    StackOverflowQuestion frame = new StackOverflowQuestion();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /** A method that studies the {@link JPanel} and its sub-{@link JPanel}s, iterating through all the component tree.
     * 
     * @param c
     * @param tab
     */
    public static void analyzeLayoutsOfComponentAndSubComponents(JPanel c, int tab) {
        System.out.println(repeatChar('\t', tab) + c.toString());
        for(int i=0 ; i<c.getComponentCount() ; i++)
            if( c.getComponent(i) instanceof JPanel )
                analyzeLayoutsOfComponentAndSubComponents( (JPanel)c.getComponent(i), tab+1 );
    }
    
    public static String repeatChar(char c, int tab) {
        StringBuffer support = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0 ; i<tab ; i++)      support.append(c);
        return support.toString();
    }
    
        
        
    
    
    public class Fieldset extends JPanel {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1464052286624448783L;
        
        /** The {@link Border} of {@code this} {@link Fieldset}.                */
        private Border border;
        /** The {@link JPanel} responsible for the layout management.           */
        public JPanel layoutPanel;
            
        /** Creates a new {@link Fieldset}. 
         * 
         * @param colorBorder The {@link Color} of the border. If {@code null}, {@code Color.BLACK} is chosen.
         * 
         */
        public Fieldset(String titleFieldset, JPanel panel, Color colorBorder) {
            super();
            
            this.border = new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(colorBorder == null ? Color.BLACK : colorBorder), titleFieldset);
            this.setBorder(border);
            this.layoutPanel = panel;
            
            super.add(layoutPanel);
        }
        
        public Component add(Component component) {
            this.layoutPanel.add(component);
            return component;
        }
            
    }


    public class AltBoxLayout_JPanel extends JPanel {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8204033141468207723L;
        
        private JPanel layoutPanel;
        
        /** Creates a new {@link AltBoxLayout_JPanel}.
         * 
         * @param axisOrientation A constant from the {@link BoxLayout} class representing the chosen insertion axis.
         */
        public AltBoxLayout_JPanel(int axisOrientation) { 
            // ===== INNER PANEL =====
            this.layoutPanel = new JPanel(); //This is the nested panel
            layoutPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(layoutPanel, axisOrientation));
            
            // ===== OUTER PANEL =====
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.add(layoutPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        
            System.out.println("Analysis of the components of the AltBoxLayout_JPanel:");
            analyzeLayoutsOfComponentAndSubComponents(this, 0);
        }
        public void add(JComponent component) {
            layoutPanel.add(component);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `StackOverflowQuestion` What would you call the *next* code example posted to Stack Overflow? `StackOverflowQuestion2`? Please give example code meaningful names which are relevant to the problem. Something like (looking at the title) `PanelEatsButtonExample` for instance, would be good. Another advantage is that another person is unlikely to use that name, and therefore people trying the code can put both examples in the same package in their IDE. **General tips:** 1) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, ..

Comment: .. with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Include the imports. Adding imports for entire packages would only add 4 lines of code. 4) But remove redundant comments inserted by the IDE. The code itself should include enough information in meaningful attribute & method names, combined with well .. the code itself. For special instructions, continue to use single line comments as seen above. ..

Comment: 5) For layout / component missing problems, strip out all the methods **not** dealing with that. E.G. the `repeatChar(..)` method appears suspiciously unnecessary. 6) I see no good reason here, to extend `JFrame` or either `JPanel`. What was the logic behind doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `layoutPanel` in your `Fieldset` class seems to stack the components on top of each other because it's default layout tells it to.
Just to get started, try setting a simple `BoxLayout` to it in the constructor of `Fieldset`:

```java
this.layoutPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Your button will be visible. So, the full constructor should look like this:

```java
public Fieldset(String titleFieldset, JPanel panel, Color colorBorder) {
    super();    
    this.border = new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(colorBorder == null ? Color.BLACK : colorBorder), titleFieldset);
    this.setBorder(border);
    this.layoutPanel = panel;
    this.layoutPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    super.add(layoutPanel);
}
```